# How to repeat method some times

Tags: java, android, void

I need repeat void x times. How i can make this? Thank you! 
P.S. For example, x = 3 and i need to start animation 3 times. P.S.2. Sorry for bad english

```
   public void animation (View v){
        view = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.lemon_prig);
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
        fl.addView(view);
        Random random = new Random();
        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, random.nextFloat(),
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, random.nextFloat(),
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -0.05f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.5f);
        anim.setDuration(1800);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation paramAnimation) { }
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation paramAnimation) { }
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation paramAnimation) {
                fl.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                fl.removeAllViews();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        view.startAnimation(anim);
    }
    public void limonplus(View v){
        count=count + i;  
        animation(v);
    }
```

Comment: learn programming first !!

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
   animation(v); // v is some View here.
}
```

Comment: So simple. Im dude. Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

You could use recursion to accomplish this (presuming you will not be executing this method thousands of times in a row):

```
public void animation (View v, int x){

    if(x == 0)
        return;

    //method code here

    animation(v, x-1);
}
```

Comment: Tail recursion is usually a bad idea in non-functional languages. It's formally equivalent to iteration, which doesn't involve the stack overhead and complexity of base cases.